# Drop rows from pandas DataFrame based on alternating columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to remove all rows in a dataframe between an entry and exit point in a timeseries of price data based on a bool entry and exit columns.

```
data = {'Entry': [True,True,True,False,False,False,False,True, False, False, False],
'Exit': [False,False,True,False,False,True,True,False, False, False, True]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Entry   Exit
0    True  False
1    True  False
2    True   True
3   False  False
4   False  False
5   False   True
6   False   True
7    True  False
8   False  False
9   False  False
10  False   True
```

So given the above I want to be left with

```
    Entry   Exit
0    True  False
2    True   True
7    True  False
10   False  True
```

I need to get the first True from the Entry column, then the following True in the Exit column, followed by the next True in the Entry column and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the old fashion way using `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
group = None
idx = []

for num, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(df["Entry"], df["Exit"])):
    if a is True and not group:
        idx.append(num)
        group = True
    if b is True and group:
        if idx[-1] != num:
            idx.append(num)
        group = False

print (idx)  # [0, 2, 7, 10]

print (df.loc[idx])
    
    Entry   Exit
0    True  False
2    True   True
7    True  False
10  False   True
```

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say thank you for this. The amount of time saved over the previous iterating through the dataframe is almost immeasurable.

Comment: @OldManEast Glad to know. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 entry = df[df['Entry']]
 exit = df[df['Exit']]
 idx = []
 pos = 0
for i in range(entry.shape[0]):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("bad")
        idx.append([entry.iloc[pos][0],entry.iloc[pos][1]])
    else:
        idx.append([exit.iloc[pos][0],exit.iloc[pos][1]])
        pos += 1
```

,Hope this help